# Conditional assignment to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas 1.42

Having a DataFrame with 5 columns: A, B, C, D, E

I need to assign values from columns D and E to columns A and B if the value of column C is true.
I want to achieve this in one line using the `.loc` method.

##### example

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | True | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | False | 8 | 11 |
| 3 | 6 | True | 9 | 12 |

##### expected result

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 10 | True | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | False | 8 | 11 |
| 9 | 12 | True | 9 | 12 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'A': [1, 2, 3], 
  'B': [4, 5, 6], 
  'C': [True, False, True], 
  'D': [7, 8, 9], 
  'E': [10, 11, 12]}
)

df.loc[df['C'], ['A', 'B']] = df[['D', 'E']]
```

##### actual result

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | nan | True | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | False | 8 | 11 |
| nan | nan | True | 9 | 12 |

##### workaround I figured

```
df.loc[df['C'], ['A', 'B']] = (df.D[df.C], df.E[df.C])
```

Seems pandas not getting right the to be assigned values if they come in form of a DataFrame, but it gets it right if you pack it nicely as tuple of Series.
Do I get the syntax wrong or is it a bug in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on both sides, and remove index alignment by converting [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) array:

```
m = df['C']
df.loc[m, ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[m, ['D', 'E']].to_numpy()
```

Or change the column names with [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df.loc[df['C'], ['A', 'B']] = df[['D', 'E']].set_axis(['A', 'B'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A   B      C  D   E
0  7  10   True  7  10
1  2   5  False  8  11
2  9  12   True  9  12
```

Comment: to_numpy() is great workaround but doesn't seem to answer my question. your second solution seems to clarify it for me. So if assigned from DataFrame pandas is looking to get assign values at cells with same indexes. i was getting nans because it was looking to assign value to 0, A from 0,A but he only had value for 0,D. When you renamed the column index pandas could find the value.
is it right?

Comment: @Eliy if you question is "why does this happen?", the answer is **due to index alignment performed before assignment.** My `to_numpy` approach is a workaround to avoid this.Regarding the second approach, can you provide a reproducible example for which it fails? Do you have duplicated indices?

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't recreate it with the example data.  But I did the same kind of operations, I set the axis of the right side Dataframe to have save columns index as left side data frame. I am getting the "cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels" error

Comment: Could you explain what index alignment before assignment means? isn't it as in the example on my comment?

Comment: Yes, exactly, in short you want to assign to columns A/B on the left side of the `=`, so pandas reindexes the DataFrame on the right side to have the same index/columns. In your case this leads to a DataFrame of NaNs as the columns A/B are missing on the right